# Modals not updating

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-modal

I am having an issue where the modal is showing the same exact data every time, but my cards have updated correctly. I have the modal and cards contained in a foreach loop which goes through all the records in the events database. Can someone point me in the right direction?  Thanks in advance.

*** Don't pay attention to the repeitiveness of the lists in the cards/modals. Im going to update the modal with the rest of the info after I find a fix.

```
<?php 
    foreach ($resultset as $record): ?>
    <?php $string = $record['event_description'];?>
      <div class = "col-md-4">
        <div class="card-columns-fluid" style="width: 30rem;">
          <img class="card-img-top" src='jumboHead.jpg' alt="Card image cap" height= "250px" width= "300px">

          <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li class="list-group-item"><b>Event: </b><?php echo $record['event_Name']; ?></li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><b>Description: </b><?php echo charlimit($string, 50); ?></li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><b>City/State: </b><?php echo $record['city']; ?> , <?php echo $record['event_state']; ?></li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><b>Email: </b><?php echo $record['event_Email']; ?></li>
          </ul>
          <div class="card-body">

<!-- MODAL-->


            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-md" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Event</button>
          </div>
          <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title"><?php echo $record['event_Name']; ?></h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
              <li class="list-group-item"><b>Event: </b><?php echo $record['event_Name']; ?></li>
              <li class="list-group-item"><b>Description: </b><?php echo $record['event_description']; ?></li>
              <li class="list-group-item"><b>City/State: </b><?php echo $record['city']; ?> , <?php echo $record['event_state']; ?></li>
              <li class="list-group-item"><b>Email: </b><?php echo $record['event_Email']; ?></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
        </div>
        </br>
      </div>
    <?php endforeach;?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, there might be a problem because you are making a dynamic list of modals, and all the modals have the same id, that is #myModal.

So i dont know how you are triggering the modal show, but if you are doing something like $('#myModal').show(), you are seeing always the same information because you are hitting always the same modal. You could set and id based on each $record.

Comment: I didn't know I was supposed to trigger the modal show. Im new with bootstrap and modals.The tutorial I was following didn't specify that. Could I just change the id to be based off the $record, or do I have to call the $('#myModal').show(). I currently don't have it in my code and the modals are showing, just the same one every time. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I got it actually. I just had to change the id based on the record like you said.